# Request to revert reviewers poor decision

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, specific-question

The OP clearly altered the question after it had been asked and answer.

I did a rev change back, and wouldn't you know it.. the final 3 reviewers rejected the reversion.

Is there some sort of incentive to rejecting revisions that have 2 approvals already? Because this is becoming a predictable pattern at this point.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9532026

Comment: although, somewhat in their defense.. a proposed revert should be better indicated..

Comment: I can't remember, but is there a rollback option for suggested edits?

Comment: @ryanyuyu I don't believe so (I don't see it on a site where I'm < 2k)

Comment: There's no way for reviewers to see how many approvals there are until after submitting the review (and only then by navigating back to the page).

Comment: Just reviewers being morons; nothing new here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have rolled back that question to revision 5.

The reason your attempt was rejected is probably due to the fact that it changed so much that the reviewers either expected an audit or didn't want to spend time visiting the question and its answers to figure out what was going on. As you indicated yourself, a better comment might have helped somewhat but I wouldn't count too much on that.

If you need such a massive roll-back your best bet is a chat room where a [2K-er](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) can do it for you. Their roll-backs don't enter the queue.

Answer (score 7):

> is there some sort of incentive to rejecting revisions that have 2 approvals already?

Not for approval votes, but for rejections, subtly yes there is.  If reviewers choose to <kbd>Reject</kbd> the suggestion, they are prompted with a dialog to pick the reason for rejecting it.  On this dialog, they can also see the count of other reviewers who chose specific rejection options.  This means that later reviewers who are a bit unsure on whether to reject can receive some validation from previous rejections.  After all, if two other people rejected it, that means it's probably the correct choice, right?

I think was a feature request requesting the reject votes to be hidden while reviewing, but I can't seem to find it. If you really think this is a problem, you can try to find it and see what other users think about it.

Comment: This is good and correct information, but since it is far more often the case that suggested edits are approved when they shouldn't be than the reverse, I don't think this behavior should be changed.

Comment: @NathanTuggy agreed. Also it seems I misread the question and mixed up approval and rejection votes. Updating.

Comment: I think hiding the reject votes could be a terribly bad thing. Sometimes a reviewer notices a flaw in the edit - for example, if it's language specific - that other reviewers may not pick up on. Overall I think there needs to be *more* communication between reviewers, not less. Even to the point of asking them to review other votes and confirm their decision if the vote was not unanimous.

Comment: @Rob I agree but it's always nice to let people know of other dissenting opinions. Well if I could find that feature request.